# Got problem 'Wrong number of arguments: setq, 3' when trying to open file

Tags: aquamacs

I am using Aquamacs 3.3  GNU Emacs 25.1.1, and I got the error message 'Wrong number of arguments: setq, 3' every time when I trying to open a file the first time.

How could I solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Try using `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`, then include the resulting backtrace into the question.

Comment: I finally find the problem is caused by using 'subfigure' package in my latex file. And this problem has been solved by changing 'subfigure.el'. And specific salutation is given in [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/aquamacs-devel/r9iaih8rsAg). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28155/unable-to-update-packages-on-emacs-25-1#comment43164_28155 one of the changes in emacs is that now `setq` requires an even number of arguments. If you set the `debug-on-error` variable to `t` then when you get this error you should enter the debugger and see where the error is coming from. Adding `nil` as a final argument should resolve your problem.

Comment: BTW, one can find news about this change via `C-u C-h n 25.1 RET C-s setq`.

Answer (score 1):

I finally find the problem is caused by using 'subfigure' package in my latex file. And this problem has been solved by changing 'subfigure.el'. And specific salutation is given in [thread on google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/aquamacs-devel/r9iaih8rsAg). Hope this helps.

Comment: This bug in `subfigure.el ` was [fixed](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/commit/style/subfigure.el?id=d2c7bb3aa56930c45722482fd64174b2504bb9a8) in January.  I suggest you install the latest AUCTeX version from ELPA.  I don't use Aquamacs, but if it supports package installation from ELPA, try `M-x package-install RET auctex RET`.

Comment: @ArashEsbati: it used to work fine for a long time for me, but the error returned magically.  Even with the newest AUCTeX version.  Fixing the file `subfigure.el` manually helped. :-/

Comment: @Jan - It seems you have two AUCTeX versions installed.  If you have the latest version installed, a manual fix would be impossible.  Please check your HD for different installations.  Besides, [`subfigure`](https://ctan.org/pkg/subfigure?lang=en) is deprecated; consider using [`subcaption`](https://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) which is also supported by AUCTeX.